# undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass when using 'time_ago_in_words' in Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting a strange error when trying to use the 'time_ago_in_words' function on conversation.messages.first(created_at) in rails:

```
<% conversations.each do |conversation| %>
  <% user_status = current_user.id == conversation.sender.id ? conversation.recipient : conversation.sender %>
  <li>
    <%= gravatar_for(user_status, size: 50) %>
    <%= link_to user_status.email, conversation_messages_path(conversation),
        remote: true,
        class: "conversation-names #{'current-link' if conversation == conversations.first}" %>
    <span class="delete-message"><%= link_to do %><i class="fa fa-times"></i><% end %></span>
    <p><%= truncate(conversation.messages.first.try(:body)) %><%= time_ago_in_words conversation.messages.first.try(:created_at) %></p>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass.

Comment: `conversation.messages` must be empty and therefore `first` returns `nil`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Iceman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/308731/iceman) hit the nail on the head.

In your `<li>` make sure that `conversation.message` exists before calling `.first` on it; otherwise `.first` will just return `nil`.